# Share count in amp-social-share

Tags: share, amp-html

I'm using **amp-social-share** for implementing social share on my amp page. I would like to get the **share count**. But I couldn't find any proper methods in amp docs related to this. Is there any method to get social share count in amp pages?

Answer (score 1):

The `amp-social-share` component cannot display share counts.

Currently `amp-social-share` does not do any communicating with the social platforms in regards to share counts or other data. Social share only uses endpoints for each platform (which you can see in the [default config](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-social-share/0.1/amp-social-share-config.js)) to add sharing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is a work-around to update both view-count and share count. I will use amp-list to update view and share count

Maintain an amp-state with a GET API end-point to update share count and name the state as you wish(I name it share).

Place amp-list at the starting of the body because amp-list starts rendering when the html tag is about to be visible on the page :p

```
<amp-list id="myList" src="your API end-point to update view-count" [src]=do.url>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
 </template>
</amp-list>

<amp-state id="myState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      share:{
          "url":"your API end-point to update share-count"
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

Finally, In the amp-social-share tag, add role="button" on="tap:setState({do='share'})" to the element.

This way you are in a position even to share-count of a particular social media platform your article was shared.

Reference : https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-list/?referrer=ampbyexample.com